# create and use branch in anksvn

Tags: svn, ankhsvn

I would like to ask about the proper method of using the current version of anksvn when working with visual studio 2010.

Right now I have the 'original' version of code checked into the 'trunk'. However now I would like to modify the existing code and place the modified code into a branch.

To place code into a 'branch', can you tell me which of the following should I do and/or tell me what the proper method:

1. Do I 'create a branch' first and check in a copy the original code into the branch? 
   or
2. Do I 'create a branch' first and check in the modified code into the branch?
   or
3. check out the original code to a location on my workstation, modify the code, and checkin the modifed code at the same time I 'create' a branch.
   and/or
4. Can you tell me what the proper procedures are for checking in modifed code into anksvn? Do I create a 'branch' before checking code into subversion or during the process of checking in modified code to anksvn?

Comment: Creating a branch will create a copy of your trunk into that branch; you could then work on the solution contained in the branch folder and commit your changes there, and when appropriate merge those changes back into your trunk. You might check out [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net), it's a good Windows client for subversion. AnkhSVN is useful within the VS 2010 IDE but it's easier to do some stuff in Tortoise IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a branch based on a URL or do #3 in your question, copy the current state of the working copy into a new branch.

To create a branch remotely (without considering the state of your working copy) using Ankh:

- Right click the solution -> Subversion -> Branch Solution
- Choose Head/Latest version to copy the trunk (or current branch) you're working in to a new branch.
- Enter a branch name after the url already present in to 'To:' box. This box does a best-attempt to guess the location of the branches directory (if you want to create a tag, you'll have to change 'branches' into 'tags).
- Enter a log message
- Optionally select "Switch to branch". This will change your working copy to point to the branch. When using branches for release maintenance I personally prefer to keep separate working copies for each branch.
- hit OK

In the same dialog you can also select 'working copy', instead of 'Head/Latest version'. In that case you copy the current state of your working copy to the branch.

The last option is "Specific version". Here you can browse the history of the current location in the repository to find the exact moment in time where you want to create the branch. The rest of the procedure is the same.

Comment: I hav the following additioanl questions to ask which are: 1. what is the recommended method for creating a branch? Use one of your comments and/or use the answer, "Creating a branch will create a copy of your trunk into that branch; you could then work on the solution contained in the branch folder and commit your changes there, and when appropriate merge those changes back into your trunk". 2. what is the difference between a branch and a tag? 3. When I want to place the 'new'code back into the trunk to represent the production, how do you accomplish this task (use merge)?

Comment: See the [docs](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/faq/ankh_overview.html) for info on that. There's no difference between a tag and a branch, except that they're supposed to be used different. You shouldn't commit to a tag, it's just to mark a release for example.